# Redirect to Angular app

Tags: angularjs

I tried google to search the answer but may be I am not asking the correct question.

My Scneario is, I have an angular app(APP1) with a grid. The grid has a link in one of its cell which points to an external asp.net web application(APP2). When the user clicks on the link he/she will be navigated to APP2, where they will perform some actions. Once done the user will click a button on APP2 which will save the data and generate an ID and Navigate back to APP1(angular app).I need to get hold of this id that is returned from APP2 and do some operations in APP1.

Let me know if its not clear what I am trying to do.

App1(angular)->App2/someparameter(asp.net webform app)->App1/id(angular)

How can I achieve this?

Comment: is the id you try to catch in the URL from app2? if so you could use the $routeParams service to catch the id.

Comment: Use ngroute or ui-router for this, see ngroute example [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route#example). I think you're trying to use optional parameters in your application so you can set this id in the url in APP2.

Comment: The App2 sends me multiple parameters, and before I land on any angular page I need to save that data and then navigate to the main page. Right now what I did is I captured the parameters before page load and set a flag which tells the maincontroller that this was a redirect. The main controller then picks the params, saves the data and then navigates to the required view.